# Can I re-attach a (ZFS) EBS volume when starting a new EC2 instance?

Tags: solaris, amazon-ec2, zfs, amazon-ebs

I'd like to use an OpenSolaris EC2 instance as a DB server, using an external EBS volume connected to a ZFS pool.

If I set-up the ZFS pools then bundle-up the EC2 image, could I terminate the instance then safely re-attach the existing EBS volume (with data) to a new EC2 instance after it boots?

My main concern is if the instance terminates unexpectedly. I would ideally like to bring up a new instance and automate the re-attachment of the EBS volume but I'm not sure whether I could store the AMI with the pool structure already set, or whether I'd have to issue some commands at start-up to build the pool structure after attaching the volume.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t used ZFS on EBS, so I don’t know if there are specific wrinkles related to that (there shouldn’t be).

When moving ZFS pools between “machines” (real or virtualised), you’re supposed to `export` the pool before `import`ing into the other. It’s not strictly necessary, but it makes things happen more smoothly.

[This article on migrating ZFS storage pools](http://docs.huihoo.com/opensolaris/solaris-zfs-administration-guide/html/ch04s06.html) may give you the heads-up you need.

Comment: Any idea how this works with separate cache and intent-log devices?

Comment: I’m guessing your plan is to not move the cache and log devices alongside the pool itself? If so, (caveat: I have no personal experience of doing this), I’d err on the side of caution and remove them prior to export and re-add as necessary after import on the other machine. I could very well be wrong, but I suspect ZFS will discover the cache and intent log devices are absent and trip a (non-fatal) error condition.

If you are going to move all of the devices together, then just an `export` and `import` should theoretically just work. If not, then you’ll have to remove and re-add them.

Comment: Unless you're running an old version Solaris 10, the pool will import just even when SSDs aren't present. L2ARC devices are safe caches, they are always empty on mount. Assuming a clean unmount (with or without export) ZFS Intent Log (ZIL) devices will also have no useful data. The ZIL is only ever read following a crash/dirty unmount so any uncommitted transactions can be replayed.